# How to iterate through methods of instances to get a representation string

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm trying to make a pension tax calculator and have created a class "Client" that will accept inputs from two separate users and calculate their taxes based on these inputs.

Is there a cleaner way for me iterate through each client than to repeat this code?

```
client1 = Client.from_input()
print(client1.name, 'Maximum pension contribution you can make this tax year: ', client1.get_maximum_contribution())
print(client1.name, 'Maximum pension contribution your employer can make this year: ', client1.get_carryforward() + client1.get_remaining_aa())
print(client1.name, 'Remaining annual allowance: ', client1.get_remaining_aa())
print(client1.name, 'Carryforward available: ', client1.get_carryforward())

client2 = Client.from_input()

print(client2.name, 'Maximum pension contribution you can make this tax year: ', client2.get_maximum_contribution())
print(client2.name, 'Maximum pension contribution your employer can make this year: ', client2.get_carryforward() + client1.get_remaining_aa())
print(client2.name, 'Remaining annual allowance: ', client2.get_remaining_aa())
print(client2.name, 'Carryforward available: ', client2.get_carryforward())
```

If anybody wants the full code or if it's relevant:

````
```# import datetime
# currentyear = datetime.date.today().year
# year3 = (datetime.date.today().year - 3)
# year2 = datetime.date.today().year - 2
# year1 = datetime.date.today().year - 1
aathreshold = 240000
aallowance = 40000
maxaareduction = 36000


class Client:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, bonus, intdiv, employeepercent, employerpercent, pensionlump, salaryexchange,
                 deathbenefits, year3contribution, year2contribution, year1contribution):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.bonus = bonus
        self.intdiv = intdiv
        self.employeecontribution = salary * (employeepercent / 100)
        self.employercontribution = salary * (employerpercent / 100)
        self.pensionlump = pensionlump
        self.salaryexchange = salaryexchange
        self.deathbenefits = deathbenefits
        self.totalgross = salary + bonus + intdiv
        self.totalannualpensioncontributions = self.employeecontribution + self.employercontribution + self.pensionlump
        self.year3contribution = year3contribution
        self.year2contribution = year2contribution
        self.year1contribution = year1contribution

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        return cls(input('Name: '),
                   int(input('Salary + Bonus: ')),
                   int(input('Bonus & Comission: ')),
                   int(input('Interest & Dividends: ')),
                   int(input('Employee gross workplace contribution % : ')),
                   int(input('Employer gross workplace contribution % :')),
                   int(input('Lump sum contributions: ')),
                   int(input('Employment income given through salary exchange')),
                   int(input('Taxed lump sum death benefits: ')),
                   int(input('Please enter your pension contributions for 2018: ')),
                   int(input('Please enter your pension contributions for 2019: ')),
                   int(input('Please enter your pension contributions for 2020: '))
                   )

    def get_carryforward(self):
        def cap_carryforward(contribution):
            if contribution > aallowance:
                contribution = aallowance
                remaining_allowance = aallowance - contribution
                return remaining_allowance
            else:
                remaining_allowance = aallowance - contribution
                return remaining_allowance

        year3remallowance = cap_carryforward(self.year3contribution)
        year2remallowance = cap_carryforward(self.year2contribution)
        year1remallowance = cap_carryforward(self.year1contribution)
        cf_allowance = year3remallowance + year2remallowance + year1remallowance
        return cf_allowance

    def get_threshold(self):
        threshinc = self.totalgross - self.pensionlump - self.employeecontribution\
                    + self.salaryexchange - self.deathbenefits
        return threshinc

    def get_adjustedincome(self):
        adjustedinc = self.totalgross + self.employercontribution - self.deathbenefits
        return adjustedinc

    def get_remaining_aa(self):
        taperexcess = 0
        if Client.get_adjustedincome(self) > aathreshold:
            taperexcess = (Client.get_adjustedincome(self) - aathreshold) / 2
            if taperexcess > maxaareduction:
                taperexcess = maxaareduction
        annualallowance = aallowance - taperexcess
        remaining_aa = annualallowance - self.totalannualpensioncontributions
        if remaining_aa <= 0:
            remaining_aa = 0
        return remaining_aa

    def get_maximum_contribution(self):
        combinedallowance = (Client.get_remaining_aa(self) + Client.get_carryforward(self))
        if (self.salary - combinedallowance) <= 0:
            maxcontribution = self.salary
            return maxcontribution
        elif (self.salary - combinedallowance) > 0:
            maxcontribution = combinedallowance
            return maxcontribution



client1 = Client.from_input()
print(client1.name, 'Maximum pension contribution you can make this tax year: ', client1.get_maximum_contribution())
print(client1.name, 'Maximum pension contribution your employer can make this year: ', client1.get_carryforward() + client1.get_remaining_aa())
print(client1.name, 'Remaining annual allowance: ', client1.get_remaining_aa())
print(client1.name, 'Carryforward available: ', client1.get_carryforward())

client2 = Client.from_input()

print(client2.name, 'Maximum pension contribution you can make this tax year: ', client2.get_maximum_contribution())
print(client2.name, 'Maximum pension contribution your employer can make this year: ', client2.get_carryforward() + client1.get_remaining_aa())
print(client2.name, 'Remaining annual allowance: ', client2.get_remaining_aa())
print(client2.name, 'Carryforward available: ', client2.get_carryforward())
````

Comment: Do you want to iterate over instances of clients, or over the methods of a single instance, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method to your `Client`-class to define how the string-representation of your objects should look like. E.g.:

```
import os
...
class Client:
    ...
    def __str__(self):
       line1 = f"{self.name} Maximum pension contribution you can make this tax year: {self.get_maximum_contribution()}"
       line2 = f"{self.name} Maximum pension contribution your employer can make this year:  {self.get_carryforward() + self.get_remaining_aa()}"
       line3 = f"{self.name} Remaining annual allowance:   {self.get_remaining_aa()}"
       line4 = f"{self.name} Carryforward available:   {self.get_carryforward()}"
       return os.linesep.join([line1,line2,line3,line4])
```

If you do that you can just do `print(client1)` in your code.
Alternatively, you can just name this method `getstring` and do it like this `print(client1.getstring())`.

If you want to iterate though your clients you can do it like this:

```
client_list = [Client.from_input() for _ in range(num_clients)]
for client in client_list:
    print(client)
```

To create a list of `num_clients` with your `from_input` method and print them all out.

Comment: Under circumstances such `__str__` could be quite confusing. Imagine an error message line "expected was a xxx, but got yyy" with this multiline message substituted.

Comment: Yeah you're right, edited it, so that the strings are joined afterwards.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

If I wanted to add significantly more lines of text to the object would I need to continue listing each line with os.linesep.join( [ ] ) or isthere a more efficient way?

Comment: If by efficiency you mean speed, I don't think that there's be any observable differences. In the end you'll want to limit the mount of calls to print, as those are slow(syscall) so you'll have to construct the full string at some point. Whether with string concat or or string-join shouldn't make a difference. If you mean using less lines, maybe you should post a new question where you generically ask for ideas to fulfill your use-case. One more concise method would be writing all this down in a config file for example but I cannot say how suitable that is for you without more info.

Answer (score -1):

```
def print_info_for_clients(clients):
    for client in clients:
        print(client.name, 'Maximum pension contribution you can make this tax year: ', client.get_maximum_contribution())
        print(client.name, 'Maximum pension contribution your employer can make this year: ', client.get_carryforward() + client.get_remaining_aa())
        print(client.name, 'Remaining annual allowance: ', client.get_remaining_aa())
        print(client.name, 'Carryforward available: ', client.get_carryforward())


client1 = Client.from_input()
client2 = Client.from_input()
print_info_for_clients([client1, client2])
```

If you wanted to you could move the `Client.from_input()` into the function, and pass in a number of clients to read instead, but I prefer doing it this way because I can also assign `client1` or `client2` in any number of different ways if I want.

Comment: They already have a `Client`-class, implementing `__str__` or a `getstring` method makes much more sense imho.

Answer (score -1):

A simple `for` might work depending on how many clients do you want:

```
def input_clients(how_many):
    clients = []
    for _ in range(how_many):
        client = Client.from_input()
        print(client.name, 'Maximum pension contribution you can make this tax year: ', client.get_maximum_contribution())
        print(client.name, 'Maximum pension contribution your employer can make this year: ', client.get_carryforward() + client.get_remaining_aa())
        print(client.name, 'Remaining annual allowance: ', client.get_remaining_aa())
        print(client.name, 'Carryforward available: ', client.get_carryforward())
        clients.append(client)
    return clients

input_clients(2)
```